# Linked List - Iterative add method - No getters and setters

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

Hello I have an assignement which is to create an iterative add method add(Student s) in the adequate class without getters and setters but I may create " auxilliary method" (not sure what it means) and attributs.

I've tried to make the method add in Group class :

```
public void add(Student s) {
    if ( head == null) {
        head = new Student(...); 
        // Struggling because Student constructor requires a String not a Student

    }
}
```

I could've done it by creating a getter for the name, like this 
head = new Student(s.getName());
but I'm not allowed to use getters and setters, what can I do ? thank you

```
public class Student {

    private final String name;
    private int grade;
    private Student next;

    private static int counter = 0;

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = 0;
    }

}

public class Group {

    private int groupnumber;
    private Student head;

    // Empty list & group number by default is 2
    public Groupe() {
        this.head = null;
        this.groupnumber = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a copy constructor. Like new `Student(student)`.

```
public class Student {

    private final String name;
    private int grade;
    private Student next;

    private static int counter = 0;

    public Student(Student template) {
        this.name = template.name;
        this.grade = template.grade;
    }

}
```

Or, maybe more simple:

```
public void add(Student s) {
    if ( head == null) {
        head = s; 
    }
}
```